# Error in displaying images after resizing in php

Tags: php, mysql, image, resize, blob

My image is not getting displayed after resizing it.

```
require('connect.php');

if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

  // Temporary file name stored on the server
  $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  
  $imagename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

          // Get new dimensions
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmpName);
  echo "orginal width".$width."<br/>";
  echo "orginal height".$height."<br/>";

  $new_width= $width * 0.5;
  $new_height = $height * 0.5;

  echo "new width".$new_width."<br/>";
  echo "new height".$new_height."<br/>"; //Its working fine till here.
  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpName);
  imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
  echo "My image"."<br>";
  echo '<img src="data:image/png|image/jpeg|image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode( $image_p ) . '" style="max-width:400px; max-height:300px;"/>'; 
  /* This line is not able to display the image. 
     Also tried imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);. Not working , but anyway i need to
     display image alongwith other content so i have used echo. Not sure which 
     variable i should work with to display the image and how do i do it.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing one step, encoding the image resource as a jpeg image (for example...).

You could output the result from something like [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) to a file and just serve the file or you could capture its output using output buffering and serve it as you do now.

Comment: Tried this also but no success. Isn't there a direct way to resize and display an image?